# SP 2013: How to reload page in event receiver on ribbon delete?

Tags: event-receivers, ribbon

I have an event receiver associates to a list that it is executed when an item is deleted from list by ribbon. Is there, in sharpeoint 2013, a way to reload the page that contains the list?
My list has not New/edit form.

Thanks to all.

Comment: What is the purpose you are trying to achieve by refreshing the page after event receiver runs?

Comment: Is it a custom action with javascript or a list eventreceiver?

Answer (score 0):

That would be quite tricky. As the event receiver is independent entity. 
Maybe such scenario would work:
1. EventReceiver Triggers - does its job - and creates reload flag (a new property bag) 
2. JavaScript on the page checks the property bag, when it sees that reload flag is true does refresh of the page.

Hope that helps